# Clearing textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, textbox

Is there any way to clear an asp textbox on a form after a specific amount of seconds the user started typing into it?

Ive tried with a script something like this:

```
function refreshtxt (){
    $('.fetch_results').find('textbox:text').val('');
}

timer = setTimeout('refreshtxt()', 8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant clearing *all* `input type='text'` fields in your Asp.net Web Form:

```
function refreshTxt() {
    //$("form input:text").val("");
    $("input:text").val("");
}

var timer = window.setTimeout(refreshTxt, 8000);
```

If you meant a *specific* `input type='text'` field, all server side ASP.net controls have a unique `ClientID`:

```
 function refreshTxt() {
        $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").val("");
 }

 ....
```

Hth...